# Is it worth making a layout work in IE6?

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I know this isn't a specific programming question (and I'm sorry that I have to ask it here), but is it worth the time and effort to make a layout work in IE6 as it would in other browsers? I am not even sure how many people use IE (Well, any IE that's not IE9; that one's OK).

Thank you for your answers, and sorry once again for asking a question that isn't related to programming <333.

Comment: It depends on target audience of the site you're making. The answer in most cases is "no, it's not worth it".

Comment: HTML and CSS questions have their place here thanks to the number of web application developers having to work with frontend development. So don't worry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is it worth the time and effort to
>   make a layout work in IE6 as it would
>   in other browsers?

To this question, I'd certainly answer **NO**. That does not mean you should not care about IE6 at all. The core functionalities of your website should still be accessible to them (until almost nobody will use it, but nowadays a lot of people has no other chance, like @Chris Buckler said). You don't need the fancy gradients, rounded corners, etc. just make sure they can use your website (the definition of *use* depends on what kind of website it is, of course it is not a problem if a site that demonstrates CSS3 features does not work on IE6 :) ).

In my personal opinion using `filter` and Javascript stuff to make these work in IE6 does not enhance user experience, it actually degrades it because IE6 is a painfully slow browser and these make it even slower.

The phrase you should have in mind is [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Comment: Oh, I loved the way you put it. I like this answer and it sounds very reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: I'd go further and say that the core functionalities of your site should be accessible even without any Javascript or CSS support at all.

Answer (score 4):

You tagged your question [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) and [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) (I just added the general [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [css](/questions/tagged/css) tags to it). I don't believe, then, that it's worth bothering.

To be serious though: Microsoft has launched a [campaign](http://ie6countdown.com) to send IE6 on its way out, so unless your client stipulates a business requirement to support IE6, there's no need to do so anymore.

Comment: LOL. Yeah, I would use ~filters~ (yuck) to accomplish the the same effect as css3 would for other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Instead of making it work in IE6, present a [banner telling people to upgrade](http://ie6countdown.com/join-us.html). Even Microsoft is telling people to upgrade, so that should be enough motivation for you!

Answer (score 1):

That depends, how many of your users are still using IE6?  You need to know the answer to that question before you can decide how much time it's worth to support them.

Answer (score 0):

According to w3Schools, you're looking at a 3.0% user base.  The decision is sort of yours, but our team has mostly quit coding for 6.0

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Ah, well, as much as I'd like that to be true there's this: http://w3fools.com/ ~ :(

Comment: I'm guessing we could spend a little while arguing the accuracy of the internet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is worth making it in IE6.  There are many corporations an companies (such as the one im at with 80 000 employee's) that unfortunatly, still have IE6 for a standard.

If you don't want to ignore hundres of thousands of people that work at these corporations, you should make it compatible with IE6 if possible.